# How to view pdf docs in Brower after completion of upload in Angular6 using PrimeNg with Typescript

Tags: typescript, angular6, primeng, pdf-viewer

[image: I need to view PDF doc when I click preview button pdf need to open in the same window without opening new tab or new window.]

I would like to display pdf doc as like as images in browser kindly help me in that as soon as possible